# PHP: How to show data from other model based on an id as foreign key?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, kartik-v

I've an application using yii2 framework.

My application has a db that contain tables:

1. `class` =>

   - id  => as **PK**
   - class_name
   - teacher_id
2. `student` =>

   - id
   - class_id => as **class_id** as foreign key from `class` table
   - student_name
   - age
   - sex
3. Etc

and in my index.php(*class*), I've use Kartik Gridview for showing the data of the class.
As you know, there are many actions in gridview, such as *view* button action.
Example:
My **index.php** show a data from `class` with `id` = 101 in gridView form.

### How do I can show all `student_name` from `student` table that has `class_id` = 101?

and I've this code:

#### in my class.php in my class model

```
public function getStudents() {
    return $this->hasMany(students::className(), ['class_id' => 'class_id']);
}
```

and code for my gridView

#### view.php in my class view

```
<?=
DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'condensed' => true,
    'hover' => true,
    'enableEditMode' => false,
    'mode' => DetailView::MODE_VIEW,
    'panel' => [
        'heading' => 'Data Detail',
        'type' => DetailView::TYPE_INFO,
    ],
    'attributes' => [
        'alamat_lengkap',
        'jumlah_dpp',
        'jumlah_ppn',
        'jumlah_ppnbm',
        'fg_uang_muka',
        'uang_muka_dpp',
        'uang_muka_ppn',
        'uang_muka_ppnbm',
        [
            'label' => 'Kode Objek',
            'value' => $model->students->student_name,     //this code didn't work and return error as "Trying to get property of non-object"
        ],
    ],
])
?>
```

Any help will be appriciated :), thanks :)

Comment: update you question and add the code where you invoke the view.php  (I think it's index.php) and the controller/action  for view.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `DetailView` :

```
'value' => implode(',', \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($model->fakturOutDetails, 'id', 'student_name')),
```

For `GridView` :

```
'value' => function($model) {
    return implode(',', \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($model->fakturOutDetails, 'id', 'student_name')),
},
```